# can't draw to second color attachment of QOpenGLFramebufferObject

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, fbo

I have a QOpenGLFramebufferObject that I've been writing to and reading from using texture() in my application. I've added a second color attachment to include some additional data, but it seems like no data is being written to it.

```
// creating the FBO (this has been working)
_drawFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(PAINT_FBO_WIDTH, PAINT_FBO_WIDTH, QOpenGLFramebufferObject::Depth);

// now I'm adding another color attachment
_drawFbo->addColorAttachment(PAINT_FBO_WIDTH, PAINT_FBO_WIDTH);
```

And then in my shader I write to both attachments when the shader is bound:

```
layout(location=0) out vec4 meshWithPaintColor;
layout(location=1) out vec4 primitiveId;

void main() {
    ...
    meshWithPaintColor = vec4(finalColor, 0);
    primitiveId = vec4(1,1,1,1);
```

When I try reading from this 2nd attachment using the textures()[1] value bound to a shader sampler the values always seem to be zero.

Do I need to do anything with the QOpenGLFramebufferObject to allow drawing to the second color attachment?

Comment: Did you notice this part of doc. [QOpenGLFramebufferObject::addColorAttachment()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#addColorAttachment)?: _**Note:** This is only functional when multiple render targets are supported by the OpenGL implementation. When that is not the case, the function will not add any additional color attachments. Call QOpenGLFunctions::hasOpenGLFeature() with QOpenGLFunctions::MultipleRenderTargets at runtime to check if MRT is supported._ Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes.  I can use the same check the FBO uses "QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions()->hasOpenGLFeature(QOpenGLFunctions::MultipleRenderTargets)" to confirm render targets are supported.  I've also seen multiple textures on the texture function, which are only created if that passes this same check passes internally to addColorAttachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did in fact have to call glDrawBuffers myself.  I assumed this was handled by the FBO binding, but apparently not.

```
    QOpenGLExtraFunctions* f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extraFunctions();
    GLenum bufs[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
    f->glDrawBuffers(2, bufs);
```

This seems strange to me that the FBO abstraction supports color attachments, but requires extra functions to use them.